# object oriented javascript with prototypes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this a bit more clearly.  When I extend modify the each function inside the Array prototype, How does calling func(this[i]) call the function passed into Array.each.

Since the function definition is function(func) and func is the parameter.

Does func = `function(i) { alert(i) }` and thus `func(this[i]) = { function(this[i]) { alert(this[i]) }` ?

```
Array.prototype.each = function(func) {
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    func(this[i]);
  }
};

[1,2,3].each(function(i) {
  alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that each function in JS is just an object. So `func` parameter passed to the `each` function is an object which is a function.

So calling `func(aParam)` you get the `func` parameter (which actually is a function) and call it passing the corresponding argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, function(func) is basically an anonymous function with parameter 'func'

Answer (score 0):

In your example: func = function(i) { alert(i); }

Answer (score 0):

Inside objects, `this` will assume the context of the instanced prototype (in JS every type is fundamentally an object instance of some prototype, so every type has its own prototype from which to create a new object). So, in this case, `this` will refer to the object created from `Array` prototype (that is, `[1,2,3]`).

Passing an anonymous function to the method each, allows that method to pass the element at `i` position to the function (the callback) you passed to it.

I explain:

```
iter #1: this => [1,2,3] ; i => 0 ; func => (function(i){ alert(i); })(this[i]) => 1
iter #2: this => [1,2,3] ; i => 1 ; func => (function(i){ alert(i); })(this[i]) => 2
iter #3: this => [1,2,3] ; i => 2 ; func => (function(i){ alert(i); })(this[i]) => 3
```

You can read `this[i]` as `[1,2,3][i]`.